# Two-Phase commit implementation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

Let's say, i've ABC system at ABC Location and DEF System at DEF location.

ABC System will insert the data, at the same time DEF System will update the data. How to guaranteed the entire set of operations completes, or the entire set of operations fails, and the state of the system is restored to the state it was in before any of the operations began.

I heard about, Two-Phase commit. Any info and sample? Really need technical advice.

Comment: Can't you use a distributed transaction from SQL Server?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the requirement, e.g. which technologies are used to integrate the 2 systems? In essence, yes, 2 phase commit gives you ACID capabilities across multiple resources (> 1 database, message queues, transactional web services, file systems etc). In MS technologies, [MS-DTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator) is used, although this is nicely encapsulated within `TransactionScope` in .Net. It isn't usually a good idea to attempt ACID across unreliable or slow networks, as this could result in a lot of locking.